# How to access *.mv.db file of H2 database?

Tags: java, persistence, h2, dbvisualizer

I have created database with my own program and it appeared as `mydatabase.mv.db` file.

But when I tried to access the same database with `DbVisualizer`, with apparently same parameters, it created two files `mydatabase.lock.db` and `celebrity.h2.db` and didn't see tables, created in the program.

What was the incompatibility?

**UPDATE**

both setups are follows:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are the connection details you are using for your program and `DbVisualizer`?

Comment: Try and make sure the path is using `/` and not `\` (in `DbVisualizer`)

Comment: For convenience, append `;IFEXISTS=TRUE` to avoid creating spurious database files, as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2443685/230513).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In H2 version 1.3.x, the database file `<databaseName>.h2.db` is the default. (The storage engine "PageStore" is used).

In H2 version 1.4.x, the database file `<databaseName>.mv.db`is the default. (The storage engine "MVStore" is used). The MVStore is still beta right now (November 2014). But you can disable the MVStore by appending `;mv_store=false` to the database URL.

Comment: i can confirm the `1.4.190` version of h2 will create a `<databaseName>.h2.db` instead of `<databaseName>.mv.db`(even i set `MVCC=TRUE;MULTI_THREADED=TRUE` in jdbc url). what i have to do is set `MC_STORE=TRUE` to force h2 use `<databaseName>.mv.db` file.

Comment: I think you are using an older version 1.4.190, or the database already existed. Could you check by running `select * from information_schema.settings where name like '%BUILD%'`? With version 1.4.190 you will get `190` twice as the result (`CREATE_BUILD` is the build that was used to create the database, and `info.BUILD_ID` is the current version). By the way it is `MV_STORE` not `MC_STORE`.

Comment: sorry, i find out it was caused by the database has been created before(without MVCC=TRUE). if the `<databaseName>.h2.db` exist, it seems h2 will reuse the older one rather create new one called `<databaseName>.mv.db`.

Comment: Yes if a database (created by an older version) already exists, it is used.

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer is now  several years old and since others may be looking for a more "current" solution...

To get it to work just update the H2 JDBC driver that DBVizualizer uses. Basically download the "Platform-Independent Zip" from http://www.h2database.com/html/download.html and copy the `h2/bin/h2-X.X.X.jar` file to `~/.dbvis/jdbc/` and then restart DBVizualizer so it can pick up the updated driver.

Also, make sure you remove `.mv.db` from the file name when setting the Database file name in DBVizualizer.

Answer (score 1):

**For Windows Users:**
The excellent way to read a ***.db.mv** file would be locally installing the h2 database and then running that database locally with the java command.
Then your path to the file will definitely show the data from your table until and unless any errors occur.

You can download the h2 database form:
http://www.h2database.com/html/download-archive.html
**Note:** choose the database version for H2 which supports your file.
You can install the H2 database by installing the downloaded .exe file would be around 7 MB.

then in the bin directory of H2 open a command prompt and run the command
java -jar  in my case it is

**command:** java -jar h2-1.4.200.jar

It will show the console of the H2 database on the browser

Provide the database details:
Driver Class: org.h2.Driver JDBC
URL: jdbc:h2:~/h2      "file path"
User Name:             "blank by default"
Password:              "blank by default"

Refer SS below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4a7xv.png)