# H2 Trying to access /private/var/empty directory

Tags: h2

Why is H2 trying to access the file below?

```
org.h2.message.DbException: Log file error: "/private/var/empty/test.trace.db", cause: "java.io.FileNotFoundException: /private/var/empty/test.trace.db (Permission denied)" [90034-195]
org.h2.message.DbException: Log file error: "/private/var/empty/test.trace.db", cause: "java.io.FileNotFoundException: /private/var/empty/test.trace.db (Permission denied)" [90034-195]
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168)
```

Comment: Spurious database URL, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2443685/230513)?

Comment: this is my DB URL spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:/opx/xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx;FILE_LOCK=SOCKET;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE

Comment: Did you try `;IFEXISTS=TRUE`?

Comment: I had the parameter ;IFEXISTS=TRUE then took it out. Why the existence or not of that parameter will make it got to /private/var/empty directory?.

Comment: It's just the first the thing I check when I find an empty database file unexpectedly. You might try something [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/14409/20589).